# alinear menú desplegable html css

Tags: html, css, html5

quiero su colaboración para la solución del siguiente inconveniente, requiero alinear el menú emergente, actualmente me sale con un desplazamiento y no se como hacerlo para que se despliegue debajo, muestro ejemplo
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

quiero que la parte despegable se alinee con la caja superior, además el  ancho de la caja es muy grande y deseo que adapte el tamaño del menú principal

este es el html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
 <head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
   <title>TCNhjkhR</title>
   <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fontello.css" />
   <script
     src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7e5b2d153f.js"
     crossorigin="anonymous"
   ></script>
   <script defer src="javascript/index.js"></script>
 </head>   
   <header class="header">
     
     <nav class="nav">
       
       <ul class="nav-menu">
         <li class="nav-menu-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Inicio</a>
         </li>
         
             <li class="nav-menu-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link nav-menu-link_active">SERVICIOS <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
               <ul class="submenu">
                   <li class="nav-menu">
                     <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Mecanica</a>
                   </li>
                   <li class="nav-menu">
                     <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Repuestos</a>
                   </li>
               </ul>
             </li>
         
         <li class="nav-menu-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link ">Flota</a>
         </li>
         <li class="nav-menu-item">
           <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link "
             >Cotiza</a
           >
         </li>
         
       </ul>
     </nav>
   </header>
</html>
```

y continuación el css de la caja

```
.container-submenu{
  position: relative;
}
.submenu{
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px; 
  overflow: visible;
  z-index: 400;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.submenu .nav-menu-link{
  background: #fff200;
  padding-left: 10px;
  width: 130px;
  
}
.nav-menu-item:hover .submenu{
opacity: 1;
visibility: visible;
}
.submenu .nav-menu-link nav-link{
background: #333;
padding-left:58px ;

}
```

gracias por su colaboración y espero una pronta respuesta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que se muestra en la imagen no se corresponde mucho con el código que compartes, pero me da la impresión de que el problema en el código es un **padding-left:58px** que tienes asociado a la clase ".submenu .nav-menu-link nav-link" (en la que por cierto, falta un punto y juntar las clases para que quede de este modo se aplique correctamente las propiedades que intentas darle. Quedaría del siguiente modo: ".submenu .nav-menu-link.nav-link").

He modificado ligeramente el código para que (en función del que tu compartes) los elemento queden alinéados como tu comentabas. He eliminado el padding-left y aplicado un **display:inline** al listado para que se vea más claro el ejemplo.

```css
.nav-menu > li {display:inline; }
    
    .submenu{
      position: absolute;
      top: 40px; 
      overflow: visible;
      z-index: 400;
      opacity: 1;
      visibility: hidden;
    }
    
    .submenu .nav-menu .nav-menu-link{
      background: #fff200;
      padding-left: 0px;
      width: 130px;
    }
    .nav-menu-item:hover .submenu{
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
    }
    .submenu .nav-menu-link.nav-link{
    background: #333;
    color: #ffffff;
    }
    
    .submenu > li {list-style:none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="header">
         <nav class="nav">
           <ul class="nav-menu">
             <li class="nav-menu-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Inicio</a>
             </li>

                 <li class="nav-menu-item">
                   <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link nav-menu-link_active">SERVICIOS <i class="fas fa-arrow-down"></i></a>
                   <ul class="submenu">
                       <li class="nav-menu">
                         <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Mecanica</a>
                       </li>
                       <li class="nav-menu">
                         <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link">Repuestos</a>
                       </li>
                   </ul>
                 </li>

             <li class="nav-menu-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link ">Flota</a>
             </li>
             <li class="nav-menu-item">
               <a href="#" class="nav-menu-link nav-link "
                 >Cotiza</a
               >
             </li>
           </ul>
         </nav>
       </header>
```

Espero que esto pueda resultarte de ayuda, pero si no es así por favor, comparte de nuevo tu código y deja alguna aclaración más en la pregunta o en comentarios para ver si así podemos ayudarte un poco más.